# Static generation for a subset of pages for a route, and dynamic for the rest

Tags: next.js

I have 30,000 products in my database, but only a few hundred of them have actual useful information.

I want to generate `/product/[productId]` pages statically to make the loading faster.

Statically generating all 30,000 pages fails on Vercel because it takes too long.

Is there a way to generate the `/product/[productId]` pages statically for few hundred `productId`s and dynamically for the rest?

Comment: Have you tried looking into `getStaticPaths`? [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths)

Comment: @SamyRahmani What exactly do I do with `getStaticPaths`?

Comment: Well, you can define what page will be statically generated.

Comment: @SamyRahmani I'm generating `/product/[productId]` pages, but statically for a few hundred `productId`s and dynamically for the rest. What makes it difficult is that it's the same route.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a middleware page that would refer you to the appropriate page.

Let's say `product1` should be generated dynamically and `product2` should be generated statically.

You could have `/product/[productId]` refer `product1` to `/product/dynamic/[productId]` and refer `product2` to `/product/static/[productId]`.

- In `/product/dynamic/[productId]`, you generate products dynamically.
- In `/product/static/[productId]`, you generate products statically.

Answer (score 0):

I found `fallback: true` is the solution for this. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths